# Creating a generic function that receives object with some properties

Tags: typescript

So I want to create an interface which has a property that is a function. This function must receive an object but each function that implements this interface can have different properties on the object that it receives.

This is how I went about doing it:

```
interface Some {
    fn: (data: Record<string, string>) => string
}

const first: Some = {
    fn: (data: { foo: string }) => `yes ${data.foo}`
}

const second: Some = {
    fn: (data: { bar: string }) => `no ${data.bar}`
}
```

Though this throws an error:

```
Type '(data: {    foo: string;}) => string' is not assignable to type '(data: Record<string, string>) => string'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Property 'foo' is missing in type 'Record<string, string>' but required in type '{ foo: string; }'.
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You want to make it generic, so maybe look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered the issue of [function parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance). You can address it by creating a [constrained generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints) for your function's `data` parameter, and requiring it when annotating the `Some` interface, like so:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EA8AROMOZCAD0hABMBnZAJQgXSkp2rClAHMAaZdziC4A+YcgDeAKGTIYIAFzIAFJUJxFBIgEpkAXjEDuAbkkBfSZKYh2s4FHaKM2HONnp0iw0OSmxuidKyCsqq2npiAAYAnhC0ACTioXAAdDDuphE8ZiaW6NZg-Ix5lI5YuK4ARnBQnhzcPn4BMnKKKmo6+sgRIOjICUnJVVAZWaYmQA)

```ts
interface Some<Data extends Record<string, string>> {
  fn: (data: Data) => string;
}

const first: Some<{ foo: string }> = {
  fn: (data) => `yes ${data.foo}`,
};

const second: Some<{ bar: string }> = {
  fn: (data) => `no ${data.bar}`,
};
```

---

In response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73844183/creating-a-generic-function-that-receives-object-with-some-properties/73844324?noredirect=1#comment130391348_73844324):

> Is there a way to do it without having a Generic on the entire interface and only on the function instead?

No — it's still an issue of function parameter bivariance.

I think you're probably interested in the `satisfies` operator ([upcoming in TS `4.9`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator), PR at [ms/TS#46827](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46827)). Until then, you could use a constrained identity function with a more relaxed `fn` type, like in the example below — if the parameter(s) of the `fn` method aren't relevant to other methods in the object, then you don't need to constrain them in the `Some` interface and you can just constrain the return type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2KDeAoZZGEALmQAoATOMOMuEATwEpkBeAPmQGcwpQA5gG48AXzx4YAVxAIwwdCGQIoEGhAzYAPABVkEAB6QQlbmiwQO5bhbI7md5PkKqwUqEpvYR4vAHo-ZAB5AGkSPARFXiJgKGi2ZVV1TQhyZ0JkAIA9AH4CIlIKaloyHCJ0dDJefhABZFFWTmQAA0YIMwASHGK4ADoYCtFmgBoxZhF-QNDwyJBo7ghZynZEtUgUtPzCbLzCYjIqGjonZAAjOCgqvkF6xq5mkHRkLp7e86gh0YaJgOQAUSgUHQlwiUTAyDAAAtYssEio1hoLJs9oVDiUTucAF5XGp1BrsLivLG9AA2EFqUOGmQAVPkAH50vA6RgABxQAHI0cccFicYIhPimiApJhTtB2chgGZHuC4NxuMABCA4KcyRCnmBWRyufQmHceNdauzevlmWzkOzhaLxZLpehZfLFcrVSgwBqtRbqoJjeQAEwAZl9vtY1L8YxEQA)

```ts
interface Some {
  fn: (data: any) => string;
}

function createSome<T extends Some>(some: T): T {
  return some;
}

// OK:
const first = createSome({
    //^? const first: { fn: (data: { foo: string; }) => string; }
  fn: (data: { foo: string }) => `yes ${data.foo}`,
});

// OK:
const second = createSome({
    //^? const second: { fn: (data: { bar: string; }) => string; }
  fn: (data: { bar: string }) => `no ${data.bar}`,
});

// Error:
const third = createSome({
  fn: (data: { baz: string }) => data.baz.length, /*
  ~~
Type '(data: {baz: string;}) => number' is not assignable to type '(data: any) => string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322) */
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having a Generic on the entire interface and only on the function instead?
Because if I have an interface with 10 properties, it feels weird to me that I need to pass a Generic to the entire interface.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73844183/creating-a-generic-function-that-receives-object-with-some-properties/73844324?noredirect=1#comment130391348_73844324) @user3467713 See update

Comment: Awesome, thanks! will be waiting for the "satisfies" operator.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
interface Some<T extends object>{
    fn: (data: T) => string
}
```

Or this:

```js
interface Some<T extends Record<string, string>> {
    fn: (data: T) => string
}
```

And then when creating object:

```js
const first: Some<{ foo: string }> = {
    fn: (data) => `yes ${data.foo}`
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having a Generic on the entire interface and only on the function instead?
Because if I have an interface with 10 properties, it feels weird to me that I need to pass a Generic to the entire interface.